# Installing a Libreoffice extension for all users

Tags: libreoffice

I want to install a LibreOffice extension for all users on my computer.
(Ubuntu 16.04, LibreOffice 5.1)
I click on the extension, select "Install for all users" and "Install for current user". Installation works  only for current user. It does not even ask for administrator's password.

I also tried to install with command

```
$ sudo unopkg add --shared <extension.oxt>
```

At first it asked to delete lock file  `~/.config/libreoffice/4/.lock`
After removing this file it said

```
ERROR: [context="user"] caught unexpected                               com.sun.star.ucb.InteractiveAugmentedIOException: an error occurred during file opening

unopkg failed.
```

Then I tried to install it as a root:

```
$ sudo -s
# lowriter
```

Opened an Extension Manager in LibreOffice and received an empty window with a Fatal Error.

Is there a way to install an extension for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this problem is a known bug [100307](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100307).
 This bug has been reported almost two years ago. Nobody is working on it :(